# Typescript import error of mdc module

Tags: angular, typescript, web, material-components

I'm new to TypeScript. And I can't import `mdc-checkbox` as it's described in the [docs](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-checkbox).

What do I have to do to fix this error?

[image: Error: Cannot find module <code>@material/checkbox</code>]

Comment: How did you installed Material?

try running `npm install angular-material --save`

Comment: Hi @Andrius. I simply cloned a seed project https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/framework-examples/angular2

Comment: So, I guess you should run `npm install` after cloning a project;

Comment: haha. i really have experience with npm. So of course i did this

Comment: Great, then, what did you do after cloning repo and running `npm install`

Comment: Nothing. It has a dependency of checkbox. More over webstorm opens me the directory of @material/checkbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143006/discussion-between-v-kalyuzhnyu-and-andrius).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found explanation
haha, very simple

```
// Since we don't have typings (yet) we require mdc-checkbox manually.
const {MDCCheckboxFoundation} = require('@material/checkbox');
```